# How to automatically detect when textbox changes text in my code?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is my code. How to automatically detect when textbox changes text in my code?

```
     $('input#name').text('content',function()  {
       var name = $('input#name').val();
       if($.trim(name) != ''){
       $.post('getphp/getpartnerposition.php', {name: name}, function(data){
       $('input#position2').val(data);
     });
}
});
```

Comment: Have tried jquery on change event?

Comment: @ParthPanchal thanks bro! sorry I'm new to this. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code, it might help you

```
$('input#name').on('change',function()  {
       var name = $('input#name').val();
       if($.trim(name) != ''){
       $.post('getphp/getpartnerposition.php', {name: name}, function(data){
       $('input#position2').val(data);
     });
}
});
```

Comment: Note that the change event only fires if the text was change when the element loses focus.